# How to reduce the submenu loading delay in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

If I want to use the `Arc Tool`, I click & hold the `Line Tool` icon and then I count,

*1 Mississippi* ...

*2 Mississippi* ...

And then the submenu appears.

Is there a way to reduce this lag? Or is there a keyboard shortcut to open submenus?

[image: Illustrator Line Tool Submenu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Illustrator and Indesign you can basically click the icon and drag to the right and the submenu appears pretty much instantly, only that you have to keep button pressed down and release it over the right menu item.

That also works in photoshop, but I like to right click in it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no to both questions.

You can drag the submenu out to be it's own tool panel though. Simply click the bar on the right side of the submenu and it will become it's own panel.

Comment: There is a push to get the AI team to add the control-click/right-click functionality to the tool panel similar to how you control/right click in Photoshop to bring up the sub tools.

Comment: That's how I expected Illustrator to work. Right now the two feel like products from different companies.

Comment: yeah.. for being a "unified" UI.. it's not very "unified" :)